# Segmentation fault sending a struct through TCP socket

Tags: c++, tcp

I'm writing a simple program about TCP Socket. What I'm going to do is send whatever 1000 data structure from client to server, but it display segmentation fault....

This is my server:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

#pragma pack(1)
struct student
{
    int id;
    string name;
};

main()
{
   struct sockaddr_in socketInfo;
   socklen_t fromlen;
   int socketHandle;
   int portNumber = 8080;

   bzero(&socketInfo, sizeof(sockaddr_in));  // Clear structure memory

   // create socket

   if((socketHandle = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
   {
      close(socketHandle);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   // Load system information into socket data structures

   socketInfo.sin_family = AF_INET;             //IPv4
   socketInfo.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); // Use any address available to the system
   socketInfo.sin_port = htons(portNumber);      // Set port number

   // Bind the socket to a local socket address

   if( bind(socketHandle, (struct sockaddr *) &socketInfo, sizeof(socketInfo)) < 0)
   {
      close(socketHandle);
      perror("bind");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   listen(socketHandle, 1);

   int socketConnection;

   while(1)
   {
   cout<<"Waiting to connect ..."<<endl;
   if( (socketConnection = accept(socketHandle, NULL, NULL)) < 0)
   {
      cout<<"Fail!!"<<endl;
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   //close(socketHandle);

   int rc = 0;  // Actual number of bytes read
   struct student buf;

    while(1)
    {
        rc = recv(socketConnection, &buf, sizeof(struct student)+1, 0);
        cout<<"Recieve = "<<rc<<endl;
        if (rc<=0)
        break;

        cout<<buf.id<<endl;
        cout<<buf.name<<endl;
    }
    }
}
```

This is my client:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
using namespace std;

unsigned long inet_addr(const string a);

string int2str( int val )  // interger convert to string
{  
    ostringstream out;  
    out<<val;  
    return out.str();  
}

#pragma pack(1)
struct student
{
    int id;
    string name;
};

main()
{
   struct sockaddr_in remoteSocketInfo;
   struct hostent *hPtr;
   const char *remoteHost="localhost";
   int socketHandle;
   int portNumber = 8080;

   bzero(&remoteSocketInfo, sizeof(sockaddr_in));  // Clear structure memory

   if((hPtr = gethostbyname(remoteHost)) == NULL)
   {
      cerr << "System DNS name resolution not configured properly." << endl;
      cerr << "Error number: " << ECONNREFUSED << endl;
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }


   if((socketHandle = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
   {
      close(socketHandle);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   // Load system information into socket data structures
   memcpy((char *)&remoteSocketInfo.sin_addr, hPtr->h_addr, hPtr->h_length);
   remoteSocketInfo.sin_family = AF_INET;
   remoteSocketInfo.sin_port = htons(portNumber);      // Set port number

   if(connect(socketHandle, (struct sockaddr *)&remoteSocketInfo, sizeof(sockaddr_in)) < 0)
   {
      close(socketHandle);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   struct student buf[1000];

    for (int i=0; i<1000; i++)
    {
        buf[i].id = i+1;
        buf[i].name = "student_" + int2str(i) + "00";
        send(socketHandle, &buf[i], sizeof(struct student)+1, 0);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Waiting to connect ...
Recieve = 13
1
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that one of the fields in `struct student` is a `std::string` object. This can't be sent across the wire directly like you're doing.

Instead, either change it to a fixed-size character array something like this...

```
struct student
{
    int id;
    char name[100];
}
```

... and write your name into there. Or you'll have to send it across the wire in a different way.

Comment: This is correct. Instead of doing it the dirty way, you could make use of serialisation (protobuf/json or similar), or define your own protocol where you prepend the size of the number and the size of the char [] for variable size.